# css pseudo element wont show

Tags: html, css, navigation, pseudo-element

I am making a navigation menu (following a tutorial), and to make the nav-icon I apparently have to use pseudo elements. Normally that would be fine, but this time, they wont show at all...

Is there something wrong with my code/is there a better way to make the icon?

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #FFF
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a {
    color: hsla(37, 39%, 72%, 1.00);
    text-decoration: none;
}
li{
    list-style: none;
}
.header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: block;
    background:url(img/background.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
.logo {
    font-size: 4em;
    color: #FFF;
    line-height: 1.1;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: hsla(152, 40%, 20%, 1.00);
    margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.nav-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70px;
    right: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
       user-select: none;
}
.nav-icon .icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #333;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
}

.nav-icon .icon::before 
.nav-icon .icon::after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-icon .icon::before {
    top: -10px;
}
.nav-icon .icon::after {
    top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I can't see any mistake here. So, it will be better if you can also add your HTML markup and create a demo or snippet showing your problem

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed semicolon `;` in some lines and comma `,` in

```
.nav-icon .icon::before ,
.nav-icon .icon::after {
    content: "";
    width: 50px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FFF
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
```

that fixes what u were looking for